# Angular 6 unit test case to validate button disable fails when using disable but not disabled querySelector attribute

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am new to Angular and trying to write 2 unit test cases using Jasmine.  One test for when a button is enabled and one test when the button is disabled.
This is the requirement....when a user enters valid data in a textbox, the button is enabled.  If the user enters invalid data in the textbox, the button is disabled.  The initial value is disabled.
This is the textbox and button html:

```
<input
      type="text"
      matInput
      formControlName = 'triplegOriginControl'
      [(ngModel)]="leg.originId"
      [matAutocomplete]="autoTripLegOrigin"
      class = 'trip-origin-input'
      (keydown.Tab)="onKey($event)"
  />

  <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoTripLegOrigin="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of triplegOriginOptions | async"
      [value]="option"
    >
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-error *ngIf="triplegForm.controls['triplegOriginControl'].hasError('invalid')">
    Please select a valid location
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
....
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<button
  mat-raised-button
  color="primary"
  id="mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id"
  [disabled] = !triplegForm.valid
>
  GET RATE
</button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

We have a custom validator that verifies if the textbox input is in the location list.
This is the constructor to use the validation function:

```
"triplegOriginControl": new FormControl(null, [ ValidateLocation(this.fetchDataService.locationArray)])
```

This is the 2 unit tests.

```
describe('Enable or Disable Get Rates Button', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
       fetchDataService.locationArray = ["STOC/4958", "NSGR/4143", "ZCRC/416", "NSGR/4143"];
     });

    it('should enable the button when Origin and Destination are valid', (done) => {
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      const originIdInput = compiled.querySelector(
        ".trip-origin-input"
      );
      originIdInput.value = "STOC/4958";
      originIdInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));

      const destinationIdInput = compiled.querySelector(
        ".trip-destination-input"
      );
      destinationIdInput.value = "NSGR/4143";
      destinationIdInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
      fixture.detectChanges();

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.leg.originId).toBe('STOC/4958');
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.leg.destinationId).toBe('NSGR/4143');
        expect(compiled.querySelector('#mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id').disable).toBeFalsy();
        done();
      });
    });

    it('should disable the button when Origin and Destination are invalid', (done) => {
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      const originIdInput = compiled.querySelector(
        ".trip-origin-input"
      );
      originIdInput.value = "546";
      originIdInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));

      const destinationIdInput = compiled.querySelector(
        ".trip-destination-input"
      );
      destinationIdInput.value = "NSGxx/43";
      destinationIdInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
      fixture.detectChanges();

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.leg.originId).toBe('546');
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.leg.destinationId).toBe('NSGxx/43');
        expect(compiled.querySelector('#mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id').disable).toBeTruthy();
        done();
      });
    });
  });
```

When using:

```
expect(compiled.querySelector('#mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id').disable)
```

the first test(Valid test) fails.
**ERROR:  Expected true to be falsy.**
When the attribute **disabled** is used, the valid test passes.

When using

```
expect(compiled.querySelector('#mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id').disabled)
```

the second test (invalid test) fails.
** Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.**
When the attribute **disable** is used, the invalid test passes.

What is the difference between the attribute **disable** vs **disabled**?
The code works as expected.  When a user enters an invalid value the button is disabled.  When entering a valid value the button is enabled.
How to correct these test cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `.disable` disables the input using JavaScript/HTML and I am not sure what `.disabled` does. I would check the attribute using attribute selector.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

1.) `compiled` is still referring to the DOM/HTML before the changes and change detection, you need a new reference every time there are changes.

2.) Use the [disabled] attribute CSS selector and see when it is present or when it isn't.

Try this, I have added comments:

```
    it('should enable the button when Origin and Destination are valid', (done) => {
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      const originIdInput = compiled.querySelector(
        ".trip-origin-input"
      );
      originIdInput.value = "STOC/4958";
      originIdInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));

      const destinationIdInput = compiled.querySelector(
        ".trip-destination-input"
      );
      destinationIdInput.value = "NSGR/4143";
      destinationIdInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
      fixture.detectChanges();

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.leg.originId).toBe('STOC/4958');
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.leg.destinationId).toBe('NSGR/4143');
        // since you did fixture.detectChanges, you need a new reference to the dom
        // compiled is still pointing to the previous instance.
        const newCompiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        // attach the attribute selector of [disabled] and expect it to not be there
        console.log(!component.triplegForm.valid); // ensure you see false here
        expect(newCompiled.querySelector('#mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id[disabled]')).toBeFalsy();
        done();
      });
    });

    it('should disable the button when Origin and Destination are invalid', (done) => {
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      const originIdInput = compiled.querySelector(
        ".trip-origin-input"
      );
      originIdInput.value = "546";
      originIdInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));

      const destinationIdInput = compiled.querySelector(
        ".trip-destination-input"
      );
      destinationIdInput.value = "NSGxx/43";
      destinationIdInput.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
      fixture.detectChanges();

      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.leg.originId).toBe('546');
        expect(fixture.componentInstance.leg.destinationId).toBe('NSGxx/43');
        // same logic here
        console.log(!component.triplegForm.valid); // ensure you see true here
        const newCompiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        expect(newCompiled.querySelector('#mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id[disabled]')).toBeTruthy();
        done();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it fails with a different error: **Error: Expected <button _ngcontent-a-c5 color="primary" id="mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id" mat-raised-button disabled>...</button> to be falsy.**

Comment: Played around and found that for the valid test it will pass if I use this as the selector: **#mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id disabled**  But the invalid test will fail if I use this selector.  If I use this selector **#mat-toolbar__get-rate-button-id[disabled]** the invalid case passes

Comment: It's a false positive, it passes because it's not there. I am confident about the CSS selector, maybe there is a type but `[]` (the hard brackets) are needed for CSS selectors. Check out the console.logs of !component.triplegForm.valid I have added and ensure you see the accurate values. If the values are accurate, maybe you need another `fixture.detectChanges()` after the `fixture.whenStable()` inside of the then callback.

Comment: The **component.triplegForm.valid** is false for both cases.  The valid flag uses the custom validator.  This validator goes to a service to get the valid locations.  The service is initialized: ** beforeEach(() => {
      fetchDataService.locationArray = ["UPPH/4097", "CACN/4030", "ZCRC/416", "NSGR/4143", "ZCRC/471", "REPH/4987"];
    });**

Comment: THat's the main problem, you need to understand why it is false for both cases. That aspect of the form is not updating or the locationArray is not binded correctly using the unit tests.

Comment: The button should be disabled.  When I run the test in debug, the button is enabled.  Not understanding how this is working

Comment: Figured it out...the location array did not have the locations that I had entered.  So the case was correctly invalid because the locations were not in the array.  THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.